# DocuSign API plans, Partner Integrations, doubts

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am struggling to understand how to approach the docusign API implementation in the application developed by my company.
The aim is to integrate the APIs to then simply forward the documents to be signed to recipients, and then taking back them from docusign and updating internal statuses for the workflows of our application.
I cannot really understand how to proceed since our application is sold and licensed to customers. I have understood that in this case a Partner Integration with docusign is required: does it have any cost for my company?
Then, we develop the integration and use the docusign account of our customers, the account is actually configured in our application and used to send documents?

Docusign Connect is another unclear point: it is available only to specific accounts (not clear which ones), does it mean that our customers should pay for a specific account plan to docusign in order to be enabled to use the webhooks of our integration in our application? Or is my company Partner account to be enabled to this functionality?

And finally, what is the sense of a developer account (and different prices..)? Should I buy a developer plan, or is it our customer which needs to have it?

Really unclear and I'm astonished that such information is not explained on the Docusign website. Please help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your qeustions

> I have understood that in this case a Partner Integration with
> docusign is required: does it have any cost for my company?

No, it's not required, but it can be useful if you are an ISV. There is not cost to build an integration, but to go live you need to have a production account. The assumption here is that the integration will be used, which cost money in the production env.

> does it mean that our customers should pay for a specific account plan
> to docusign in order to be enabled to use the webhooks of our
> integration in our application? Or is my company Partner account to be
> enabled to this functionality?

All accounts including DocuSign Connect, but not all the features of Connect are included, as some features are not part of the account. If you just need webhooks - no worries, if you have more specific requirements - there's a possibility as specific SKU would be needed.

> And finally, what is the sense of a developer account (and different
> prices..)? Should I buy a developer plan, or is it our customer which
> needs to have it?

Developer account are free, and anyone can create them easily. You can have more than one, your customers can have them, they include almost every feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Can I ask you for more support, still? :D

Comment: I have not understood yet what to do. Ok, I can create for free a partner account for my company, and then demo accounts both for the development and for the customer and its tests. But what happens for the production? 
I don't understand which account is required for the customer, and what for we (the publisher of the software, including the docusign integration).
For what I have understood: I (the producer of the software) must have an integrator account, or no account at all (just demo). The customer who will buy the software with the integration, can use its account (standard)

Comment: And so, what is the purpose of the developer account, which has higher costs and a limited number of documents that can be sent per month? Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can create a free partner account and only your customers have to pay.
But for that - you have to become a partner first. 
Check out https://www.docusign.com/partners for more details.

Comment: you are confused. Developer accounts are free.
You mean the API plans in production. These cost money.
their purpose is not for ISVs like you but for customers with internal developers.

Comment: Thank you! Therefore my company should apply to the partner program (which has a cost, I suppose) and our customers could use their account with their own plan, without caring if it is enabled or not to use API or not, correct?

Comment: correct, all customers can use API. In fact, all of them use the API.